# Property binding not working in ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I am trying to fill a ListBox with items consisting of a grid which holds a checkbox and a textblock. I originally had only a checkbox but I need the text to wrap so I changed it to a grid with a checkbox and a textblock, with the text block doing the text wrapping.

When it was just the the checkbox, the binding worked, but now it does not. Now the correct number of items show up in the listbox but it is just an unchecked checkbox (even if I set it to checked in the code behind, see below) and a blank textblock.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lstCalibration" 
    Margin="304,95,78,24" 
    Background="#7FFFFFFF" 
    Width="211" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="auto">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox 
                    Content="" 
                    Tag="{Binding Tag}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                    Checked="CheckBoxCal_Checked" 
                    Unchecked="CheckBoxCal_Unchecked"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                    />
                <TextBlock 
                    Tag="{Binding Tag}" 
                    Text="{Binding Text}" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Code behind:**

```
foreach (Controller item in calList)
{
    //fill listbox with cals and correct checked states
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = item.Description;
    cb.Tag = tb.Tag = i;
    cb.IsChecked = calChecked[i];
    if (cb.IsChecked == true)
        noneChecked = false;
    i++;

    Grid.SetRow(cb, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(cb, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(cb);
    Grid.SetRow(tb, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(tb, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(tb);
    lstCalibration.Items.Add(grid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this, and delete that foreach loop where you programatically create all the stuff you already set up in your `DataTemplate`. It's a perfectly good `DataTemplate`, but your code isn't using it right. <strike>Get rid of `calChecked`; `_items[n].IsChecked` will now do that job.</strike>

At any time you can add a new `ListItem` to `_items` and it will appear in the list, or remove an existing one and it will vanish from the list. That's the "observable" part. Thanks to the `PropertyChanged` event raising, if you set `IsChecked` on any of these from code behind, the corresponding checkbox in the UI will automagically update.

```
public class ListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public String Text { get; set; }

    private bool _isChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set {
            _isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsChecked));
        }
    }
}
```

In your constructor in code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<ListItem> _items;
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent()

    _items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
        calList.Select(
            cal => new ListItem {
                       Text = cal.Description,
                       IsChecked = cal.WhateverElse
                   }
        ));

    lstCalibration.Items = _items;
}
```

One small change to `DataTemplate` in two places: Don't waste time binding `Tag`. In the event handlers (which you may not even need), just cast like so:

```
public void CheckBoxCal_Checked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var listItem = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as ListItem;

    //  Do whatever. listItem.IsChecked will be up to date thanks 
    //  to the binding.
}
```

XAML:

```
            <CheckBox 
                Content="" 
                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                Checked="CheckBoxCal_Checked" 
                Unchecked="CheckBoxCal_Unchecked"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                />
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding Text}" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Grid.Row="0" 
                Grid.Column="1"
                />
```

Comment: The foreach loop is actually necessary because (and I should have pointed this out in my question) the variable calList is not referring to the ListBox controller, it is a separate List variable that I use to populate the ListBox. Also the calCheked is necessary too because it is what remembers the checked states of all the items even after the UI has been altered. I will still try to apply your answer and get back to you if it worked.

Comment: @MikkelBang I don't know what a "listbox controller" is. I can see that you were using calList to populate the listbox; I'm showing you a better way to do the same thing. I see what you mean about `calChecked`.

Comment: Ah now I see what you're doing with populating the list and why I don't need the foreach loop, my bad, should have studied your code a little longer before replying. A ListBox controller is the UI element, ListBox.

Comment: Binding is working, thanks for the answer and quick replies. I'll have to fudge with it to do some things that I want it to, but you answered my question.

Comment: @MikkelBang What else do you need it to do?

Comment: Oh it's just cosmetic stuff on my end. I got it from here. Also I realize now why you were confused about "ListBox Controller", meant to say "ListBox Control"

Comment: @MikkelBang Ahhh! OK, I thought you were thinking about some MVC thing. A typo makes a lot more sense!